# Updating temp table with loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, sql-server-2012

I'm attempting to create an automated way to find the Min-Max range of certain data points. The problem is that when arranging the HUB data points (SLICs) in sequential order, many of the HUBs SLIC flows are interrupted by the SLICs of other HUBs. This provides a problem because the ranges overlap for many HUBs. Thus, I need to stop the range for the HUB name 1, start a second range for HUB name 2, then start another new range for HUB 1 again. To put in visual form:

```
HUB 1: 0101-1490
HUB 2: 1500-1501
HUB 1: 1510-1513
```

etc.,

```
+-------------------+------+
|       HUB         | SLIC |
+-------------------+------+
| MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D  | 1471 |
| MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D  | 1480 |
| MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D  | 1481 |
| MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D  | 1482 |
| MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D  | 1490 |
| WILLOW GROVE_PA_D | 1500 |
| WILLOW GROVE_PA_D | 1501 |
| MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D  | 1510 |
| MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D  | 1512 |
| MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D  | 1513 |
| WILLOW GROVE_PA_D | 1520 |
| MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D  | 1522 |
+-------------------+------+
```

I have never attempted a loop before, so I have been experimenting, but I believe I am stuck in an infinite loop. What I am attempting is to create two temp tables, the first housing the raw data which will be used to insert and update into the second table with the HUB name and the MIN and MAX SLICs for that range.

I would like the results to be as such:

```
+-------------------+------+------+
|        HUB        | MIN  | MAX  |
+-------------------+------+------+
| MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D  | 0101 | 1490 |
| WILLOW GROVE_PA_D | 1500 | 1501 |
| MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D  | 1510 | 1513 |
| WILLOW GROVE_PA_D | 1520 | 1520 |
| MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D  | 1522 | 1522 |
| WILLOW GROVE_PA_D | 1530 | 1540 |
+-------------------+------+------+
```

My query:

```
DROP TABLE SLIC5
CREATE TABLE SLIC5
(UPS_HUB nvarchar (255) NOT NULL,
SLIC nvarchar (255) NOT NULL,
PK_SLIC int NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO SLIC5
    SELECT TOP (50) UPS_HUB, SLIC, RANK () OVER (ORDER BY SLIC) PK_SLIC
    FROM SLIC

ALTER TABLE SLIC5
ADD PRIMARY KEY (PK_SLIC)

DROP TABLE #tempRAW
CREATE TABLE #tempRAW
(UPS_HUB varchar(50), SLIC nvarchar(10))

INSERT INTO #tempRAW (UPS_HUB, SLIC)
    SELECT UPS_HUB, SLIC
    FROM dbo.SLIC5
    ORDER BY PK_SLIC ASC

DROP TABLE #RANGE_TABLE
CREATE TABLE #RANGE_TABLE
(UPS_HUB varchar (50), [MIN] nvarchar (10), [MAX] nvarchar (10))

INSERT INTO #RANGE_TABLE (UPS_HUB,[MIN])
SELECT TOP (1) UPS_HUB, SLIC
FROM #tempRAW

DECLARE @currentHUB varchar, @currentMinSLIC nvarchar, @tempTableRecCount int
SELECT @currentHUB=UPS_HUB, @currentMinSLIC=[MIN] from #RANGE_TABLE
SELECT @tempTableRecCount= (SELECT count(*) from #tempRAW)

WHILE (@tempTableRecCount > 0)
BEGIN
DECLARE @loopingSLIC nvarchar, @loopingHUB varchar
SELECT @loopingSLIC=SLIC, @loopingHUB=UPS_HUB from #tempRAW
    IF (@currentHub=@loopingHUB)
        BEGIN
            IF (@currentMinSLIC < @loopingSLIC)
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE #RANGE_TABLE
                    SET [MAX]=@loopingSLIC
                    WHERE #RANGE_TABLE.UPS_HUB=@currentHUB
                    END
            END
    IF (@currentHUB <> @loopingHUB)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #RANGE_TABLE (UPS_HUB,[MIN])
                VALUES (@loopingHUB,@currentMinSLIC)
    END

DELETE FROM #tempRAW
WHERE UPS_HUB=@loopingHUB and SLIC=@loopingSLIC

SELECT @currentHUB=UPS_HUB from #tempRAW
SELECT @currentMinSLIC= SLIC from #tempRAW

SELECT @tempTableRecCount = count (*) from #tempRAW
END

SELECT * FROM #RANGE_TABLE
SELECT * FROM #tempRAW
```

Comment: Please edit your question with (1) sample data; (2) desired results; and (3) a tag with the database and version you are using (presumably SQL Server).  You can probably do what you want with a single query.

Comment: From syntax it looks like `SQL Server`. edited the post accordingly. rollback if that's not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #demo (hub nvarchar(100), slic int)

insert #demo  values 
('MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D',1471),
('MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D',1480),
('MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D',1481),
('MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D',1482),
('MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D',1490),
('WILLOW GROVE_PA_D',1500),
('WILLOW GROVE_PA_D',1501),
('MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D',1510),
('MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D',1512),
('MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D',1513),
('WILLOW GROVE_PA_D',1520),
('MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D',1522)
```

**EDIT:**

```
    WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT hub
        , slic
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY slic
            ) - RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY hub ORDER BY slic
            ) diff
    FROM #demo
    )
SELECT hub
    , MIN(slic) min_slic
    , MAX(slic) max_slic
FROM cte
GROUP BY hub
    , diff
ORDER BY MIN(slic)
```

Result:

```
hub min_slic    max_slic
MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D    1471    1490
WILLOW GROVE_PA_D   1500    1501
MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D    1510    1513
WILLOW GROVE_PA_D   1520    1520
MEADOWLANDS_NJ_D    1522    1522
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tristan, but your answer has the same range overlap I need to avoid. I also need for the script to populate the min-max (hence the loop) because we have several more hubs and SLICs that are not included in this data set that we might need in the future.

Comment: @Brian I missed that in reading your post, my bad! I fixed it now with some voodoo ;)

Comment: AWESOME! So much simpler. I like your idea of using the constant diff to create the sub-grouping of HUBs.